# Why does .Where() with a Func parameter executes the query?

Tags: c#, oracle, linq, entity-framework

Here's how my DataAccessLayer works :

```
 public Foo GetFooBy(Func<Foo, bool> filter)
 {
     var query = from item in this.DataService.FooSet select item;
     var where = query.Where(filter);
     var first = where.First();

     return first;
 }
```

I assumed the query would be run when First() is called but it's actually executed by the Where(). From the [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/bb534803(v=vs.110).aspx), I realized that .Where(Func) is an extension method defined by Enumerable, so it makes sense, but I don't understand how is it different from calling .Where() with a lambda expression.

A very easy way to be sure that .Where() materialized the data is to check query's, where's and first's type.

1. query is IQueryable, meaning nothing happend in database yet
2. where is IEnumerable, meaning the data has been materialized*
3. first is Foo

Debug and SQL traces also make it very clear that data is fetched by the .Where()

EDIT : * possibly not true since IQueryable implements IEnumerable

Comment: I'd like to know how you've reached some of your conclusions. Can you let us know... if you place a breakpoint on the line starting `var first`, has the query *definitely* run by this point?

Comment: You can verify what @spender asked for by turning on logging on the `DbContext` and simply watching the console window. If the query shows up before the `First` line I will eat my hat.

Comment: I'm in for a bit of hat-eating too...

Comment: Your edit does not encourage hat-eating. Your assumption : "where is IEnumerable, meaning the data has been materialized" is incorrect.

Comment: The fact that `where` is `IEnumerable` simply means you're in for a very inefficient query, if and when you actually try to iterate the enumerable. You're calling `Where<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Func<T, Bool> pred)` on an unfiltered query that will return the contents of your entire table. It doesn't mean you've actually executed the query yet.

Comment: sorry, I wasn't aware that IQueryable implements IEnumerable. SQL traces don't lie, though.

Comment: So the story goes like this. You've accidentally invoked `Enumerable.Where` instead of `Queryable.Where`, so your `Where` statement pulls in **ALL** rows from the DB, and performs filtering client-side. This won't happen until you execute the `First` statement. Please drop a breakpoint before `First` has executed, check the state of play, then come back to us.

Comment: You are perfectly right. Then the "only" problem is that the query might look efficient if you overlook (or don't know why it's important) the fact that the parameter isn't an expression.

Comment: Well, yes, LINQ has a few gotchas, but it doesn't prevent you from supplying an interface that forces an expression, not a Func, e.g. `bool DoSomething(Expression<Func<int,bool>> expr)`, so in `DoSomething(x=>true)` , `x=>true` is implicitly an expression.

Comment: @spender out of curiosity, do you know why is there such a (dangerous) difference between the two ?

Comment: @Trajan An `Expression` is a tree representing code. The expression tree comprising your lambda needs to be inspected and translated to SQL by Entity Framework. If you have a `Func`, that is just an arbitrary delegate; at that stage it exposes no interface for examining the source code (it may even have been composed from dynamic IL, and have no source representation).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is a very important difference between [`Enumerable.Where`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb534803(v=vs.100).aspx) and [`Queryable.Where`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb535040(v=vs.100).aspx):

`Enumerable.Where` takes a `Func<T, bool>`.

`Queryable.Where` takes an `Expression`.

Your `filter` variable is not an `Expression`, it is a `Func<T, bool>`, therefore, the compiler uses `Enumerable.Where`.

What happens then is that all rows of your `FOO` table are transferred to your client and are then filtered in memory.

As others correctly noted, the execution still happens on the call to `First()`.

**UPDATE:**
Your SQL trace doesn't prove that the materialization happens on the call to `Where`. It only proves that the filtering of the `Where` is not happening on the server side. And the reason for that is explained in my answer above.

**How to fix:**
You can easily fix this by changing your method to take an Expression instead:

```
public Foo GetFooBy(Expression<Func<Foo, bool>> filter)
{
    var query = from item in this.DataService.FooSet select item;
    var where = query.Where(filter);
    var first = where.First();

    return first;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> I assumed the query would be run when `First()` is called

That's a correct assumption.

> but it's actually executed by the `Where()`

That's either false, or you're not using a `Where` method from `System.Linq`.

> I don't understand how is it different from calling `Where()` with a lambda expression.

It's not.  Well, unless the `Queryable.Where` would have been the one executed had you provided a lambda, but in both cases execution would be deferred.

---

On a side note, your entire method body could be re-written as:

```
return this.DataService.FooSet.First(filter);
```

It'd behave identically.

Comment: I split my code in multiple lines for the purpose of this question only, to make things easier to discuss.